# How do I prevent the program from crashing?

Tags: python, selenium

## Right now the program says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]"}
```

How do I prevent the program from crashing if it doesn't find the element, to cycle over again.

```
def auto_swipe(self):                                              
    x = 0 
    while x == 0:
        sleep(0.5)
        try:
            dislike_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button')
            dislike_btn.click()
        except Exception:
            self.close_popup()

def close_popup(self):
    popup_3 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]')
    popup_3.click()
```

Comment: looks like you are getting exception from `close_popup()` method

Comment: Right, so the idea is that i'll call that method and if the pop up is there it'll click it and if it isn't it'll just rerun the auto_swipe and try again with the dislike_btn.

Comment: add `try` block in  `close_popup()` method

Comment: I've tried that and for every try, you must use a except, how would I go about doing that so that? except: exit() ?

Comment: add what you want to do if dislike_btn also not found